# Why I can't get time this way

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
    strTime=@"13:00";


    NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:strTime];
```

Everything seems fine.

Yet the content of date is nil.

Why?

What did I do wrong?

Also I changed to @"HH:mm"

```
    NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSDate * date = [df dateFromString:strTime];
```

Result is the following:

```
(lldb) po strTime
13:00
(lldb) po date
2000-01-01 06:00:00 +0000
(lldb) po strTime
15:45
(lldb) po date
2000-01-01 08:45:00 +0000
```

I think I want something closer to today's date

Comment: You need to read the documentation about the date format specifiers and see what `hh` means and then think about what you need instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose what you did wrong is not read the documentation enough.  But it's actually pretty obscure.  The [*Data Formatting Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) points you to [§8 Date Format Pattern, in Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), which says this about `h`:

> Hour [1-12]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match the 12-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (h or K); it should not match a 24-hour-cycle format (H or k). Use hh for zero padding.

And says this about `H`:

> Hour [0-23]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match the 24-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (H or k); it should not match a 12-hour-cycle format (h or K). Use HH for zero padding.

So you should try using `HH:mm` as your format:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```